# Install librets on OS X 10.8 with Python bindings

Tags: python, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew, rets

We need to install [librets](http://www.crt.realtors.org/projects/rets/librets/) on OS X with Python bindings. How do we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)
2. Run `brew edit librets`
3. Replace your recipe with [the code](https://gist.github.com/msamoylov/0ed331975dacd7b8f919)
4. Run `brew install librets`